# Repair damaged hard drives with Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have two damaged hard drives, one external, and I'm running my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on the other!

I haven't been able to repair it. I tried GParted and `mkfs` and nothing has helped.

In Windows the command `chkdsk` doesn't work for me.

What else can I try?

Comment: thnks for your answer, but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try [testdisk](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/testdisk.1.html). Be sure to boot from Live CD to check your main disk.

Comment: testdisk ! same error

Comment: there also tool named [PhotoRec](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/photorec.1.html) which ignore filesystems. I have not tried it, but perhaps it can help.

Answer (score 0):

OK thanks everybody I solved this!
For those who have the same problem there is a solution:

- Make ext2 filesystem using `mkfs.ext2`
- Then run `fsck`
- Format the disk under Windows

Comment: explain your steps, please!